# jQuery select options if value is selected then fadeIn()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a form with a select tag... I also have a duplicate form button when the user pushes it the same form duplicates underneath.

My problem is when the form duplicates and the user uses the select tag (which I have some jQuery when the user selects a certain value.... have this `fadeIn()` it's using the same class so both select tags are working together when I need it to be individual of each other.

Here's a link to the fiddle I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/ThnKc/

Here's my html

```
  <select id="print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite">
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="customSize">3</option>
   </select>

   <div class="custom_size" style="display: none;">
     Hello
   </div>

   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <select id="print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite">
     <option value="">1</option>
     <option value="">2</option>
     <option value="customSize">3</option>
   </select>

   <div class="custom_size" style="display: none;">
     Hello
   </div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
    $("#print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite").change(function(evt) {
      var selected;
      selected = $(this).val();
      if (selected === "customSize") {
      return $(".custom_size").fadeIn();
      } else {
      return $(".custom_size").fadeOut();
       }
       }).change();
```

So I just want independent behaviors for each different select tags......I can't assign it to different classes because the user might duplicate the form 10 times.......

I'm obviously new to jQuery so if you could help me out that would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See using same ids for multiple instances in a same page is invalid markup and it wont work that way. You have to do some workaround like this:

```
var i=0;
$('a').click(function () {
    $('select').last().clone().attr('id', 'print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite'+ i++).appendTo('body');
     $('.custom_size').last().clone().hide().appendTo('body');
});
$('select').each(function (i, v) {
   $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + i);
});
$(document).on('change', '[id^="print_size_"]', function (evt) {
  var selected;
  selected = $(this).val();
  if (selected === "customSize") {
     $(this).next(".custom_size").fadeIn();
  } else {
     $(this).next(".custom_size").fadeOut();
  }
}).change();
```

#### [CHECK THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ThnKc/3/)

With your lates comment:

You have to delegate the event to the parent element or `$(document)`.

Comment: this doesent work cause if i add more select tags only the two works i need it so that no matter how many select tags there are they all work independently of each other.  Because the user has the option to duplicate form

Comment: Its a case of event delegation you can try the updated answer.

Comment: @user1502223 may be you need this one. just updated the answer and the fiddle link. Try these out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite",function(evt) {
    var selected, index;
    selected = $(this).val();
    index = $("select").index(this);
    if (selected === "customSize") {
        $($(".custom_size")[index]).fadeIn();
    } else {
        $($(".custom_size")[index]).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

No idea why i had to wrap the index but I did.

P.s. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dtwigs/ThnKc/2/

Comment: Also this will capture dynamically added select boxes.  If you use .change() it will only work on the select boxes that exist on the dom at page load.